# NameError: global name 'start_responses' is not defined after modifying my myapp.wsgi file

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Previously I got the Apache is running page. Then I modified

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

I added at the top, outside of the VirtualHost tag

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1
```

Then right before the closing  tag, I added this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myapp.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my myapp.wsgi file

```
def application(environ, start_response):
status = '200 OK'
output = 'Hello World!'

response_headers= [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),('Content-Length',
                     str(len(output)))]
start_responses(status,response_headers)
```

Now I am getting a 500 Internal Server error when going to my public ip address.

This is my error.log

```
    [Sat Dec 10 16:05:36.698052 2016] [:error] [pid 12468:tid 140408204646144] [client 108.49.103.204:56866]   File "/var/www/html/myapp.wsgi", line 7, in application, referer: http://35.164.22.192/
[Sat Dec 10 16:05:36.698079 2016] [:error] [pid 12468:tid 140408204646144] [client 108.49.103.204:56866]     start_responses(status,response_headers), referer: http://35.164.22.192/
[Sat Dec 10 16:05:36.698096 2016] [:error] [pid 12468:tid 140408204646144] [client 108.49.103.204:56866] NameError: global name 'start_responses' is not defined, referer: http://35.164.22.192/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates, you named the function you are calling wrongly. The parameter to `application` is `start_response`, not `start_responses`.

Also, `ServerName` should never be an IP address in the Apache configuration. Presumably you only have a single `VirtualHost` definition, because in that case it doesn't really matter as when wrong, or Apache can't match a virtual host correctly, it will always handle your request in the first `VirtualHost` anyway.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. I had been puzzled for  while about that error. I also removed ServerName from the Apache config as suggested.